# java spring boot api-rest multipart and data transfer, the best method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

what is the best method to transfer a file and a class in multipart in spring boot 2.x.x?

I'm using this type with some problems , Class fields all get to null

```
ResponseEntity validateAndCreate(@RequestBody(required = true) ValidationCreationDTO requestBody, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request);
```

I expect the method to transfer the file and the valued class

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload a file using `MultipartFile`, then additional parameters must be loaded as part of the request, as if it were a request from an html form.

**For example**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload/image' \
--header 'Authorization: token {token}' \
 \
--form 'file=@"/Users/maksimkozlov/Pictures/363_max.jpg"' \
--form 'artifactType="image"'
```

For my example, the method signature would look like this:

```java
ResponseEntity validateAndCreate(
   @RequestParam(required = true) String artifactType, 
   @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
);
```

You can also create DTO class that will have fields with given values.

For example:

```java
public class ArtifactFile {

   private String artifactType;
   private MultipartFile file;

   // getters and setters

}
```

In such a case, you can modify the controller method signature as follows

```java
ResponseEntity validateAndCreate(
   @ModelAttribute ArtifactFile artifactFile
);
```

Another file upload option is shown in the following example.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload/image' \
--header 'Authorization: token {token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \
--data-binary '@/Users/maksimkozlov/Pictures/049_max.jpg'
```

In this case, the signature of the controller method will look like this

```java
ResponseEntity validateAndCreate(
   HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest
);
```

HttpServletRequest has several methods that will allow you to upload a file to the server:

- getInputStream() to get the input byte stream
- getContentLength() to get the upload file size

In this case, you can always pass additional information about the file through the request headers.

Comment: receive this error : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]

Answer (score 0):

```
ResponseEntity(validateAndCreate(@RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file, @RequestPart @Valid ValidationCreationDTO requestBody, HttpServletRequest request)
```

change or add (required = flag) flag based on your usecase and @Valid annotation might not be necessary for you. But it's a good standard to have bean level validations(proper). As it provides a simple first level of protection before the your request reaches the Service